# I am unable to use padRight

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft

Im trying to add zeros when necessary to a mapping but it is not working.

This is the payload im working with:

```
[
    {
        
        "groupName": "POSCH",
        
        "groupMembers": [
            {
                "dealerNumber": "262",
                
                "mainDealer": true
            },
            {
                "dealerNumber": "243",
                
                "mainDealer": false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        
        "groupName": "PRUCKNER",
        
        "groupMembers": [
            {
                "dealerNumber": "213",
                
                "mainDealer": true
            },
            {
                "dealerNumber": "262",
                
                "mainDealer": false
            }
        ]
    }]
```

Im currently writting this in order to filter the dealerNUmber that contains true in maindealer only. I believe that is in a good state but i cant add the zeros

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload map {
    groupName: $.groupName,
    dealers: $.groupMembers filter $.mainDealer == true map {
        dealerNumber: $.dealerNumber padRight(5, "0"),
        locationName: $.locationName
    }
}
```

In order to get the 262 becoming 00262.

But it is giving me this error :

```
Invalid input ',', expected ')' for the enclosed expression. (line 7, column 48):


7|         dealerNumber: $.dealerNumber padRight(5, "0"),
                                                  ^
Location:
main (line: 7, column:48)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a
couple of problems with the provided DataWeave script.

1. As per your requirement you need `leftPad` and not rightPad since you are trying to add zeros to the left of your string. You need to import it as it is in the `dw::core::Strings` module.
2. You are mixing infix and prefix notations. You can use only one of them at a time and infix is only possible when you want to call the function with 2 params.
   Refer this [documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dataweave-language-guide)

> DataWeave supports both prefix notation `(function (param1, param2))`
> and infix notation `(param1 function param2)` for function calls. Note
> that you can use **infix notation only with functions that accept only
> two parameters**.

Your DataWeave should look like this after the suggested changes:

```js
%dw 2.0
import leftPad from dw::core::Strings
output application/json
---
payload map {
    groupName: $.groupName,
    dealers: $.groupMembers filter $.mainDealer == true map {
        dealerNumber: leftPad($.dealerNumber,5, "0"),
        locationName: $.locationName
    }
}
```